# git working directory random not clean

Tags: git, github

I've got this Git repo with a weird issue causing my working directory to be randomly dirty after some interaction with github.

Normally I check my changes:

```
root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git status
    # On branch development
    # Changed but not updated:
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file1.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file2.js
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file3.html
    #
    no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Commit them:

```
root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git commit -am "my custom"
    [development e9e4235] my custom
     3 files changed, 21 insertions(+), 48 deletions(-)
```

Pull and rebase cause my changes are minor and I don't need an extra 'merge' commit:

```
root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git pull --rebase
    Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 
    Current branch development is up to date.
```

Push:

```
root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git push
    Enter passphrase for key '/root/.ssh/id_rsa': 
    Counting objects: 21, done.
    Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
    Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 1013 bytes, done.
    Total 11 (delta 9), reused 0 (delta 0)
    To git@github.com:User/MyRepo.git
       72612a8..e9e4235  HEAD -> development
```

Check my status, all changes files!! "That's weird, I didn't edit those..."

```
root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git status
    # On branch development
    # Changes to be committed:
    #   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
    #
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-4.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-5.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-6.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-7.css
    #
    # Changed but not updated:
    #   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
    #   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    #
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-4.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-5.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-6.css
    #   modified:   path-to-some-file-a-coworker-edited-in-a-previous-commit-7.css
    #
```

A reset fixes it:

```
root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git reset

root@debian:/var/www/MyDir# git status
    # On branch development
    nothing to commit (working directory clean)
```

Anyone familiar with this weird behavior?

Is this normal and am I doing something completely wrong or could this be a bug in git?

Comment: Checked line endings? `git diff` will show them clearly.

Comment: Line endings and a file system that doesn't have reliable time-stamping (i.e. FAT) would be your two biggest suspects here...

Comment: How could line endings or time-stamping be the problem when the problem is solved with a `git reset` ? And the system is a virtual debian machine on my mac.